# Element not being found

Tags: reactjs, dom

I am having an issue where I have an element, but I cannot seem to reference it without getting a null error.

```
render() {
    const getXandY = () => {
      const elment = document.getElementById("test");
      const xpos = elment.style.left;
      const ypos = elment.style.top;
      console.log(xpos);
      console.log(ypos);
    };
    return (
      getXandY(),
      (
        <div id="test" className="treeContainer">
          {this.state.configs.map((config) => (
            <div>
              <Configs configName={config.name} configNumber={config.id} />
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      )
    );
  }
}
```

any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please specify which element you have in mind.

Comment: On the initial render, `test` does not exist yet, so `getXandY` won't be able to find it

Comment: Why are you calling a function from the `return`? It doesn't return JSX, so don't do it..

Comment: @BrianThompson I am new to react so I was unaware that was an issue

Comment: @k-wasilewski I am trying to reference test. Where do I need to call the function instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sue you understand React. In `render()` function try to avoid defining functions, it's a function for just returning the JSX you want to render (you can't return nothing else there). So define your `getXandY` outside `render()`. If you really want to invoke it on rendering, simply put the function call inside, that's it. So it would look something like:

```
const getXandY = ...

render() {
    getXandY();

    return (
        <div ... />
    );
{
```